# python recursion class variable

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search-tree, inorder

Let me rewrite my question so that it is clearer. I encountered a issue on LeetCode problem: validate binary search tree.

My first solution looks something like this:

```
class Solution(object):
    def recursion(self, input, var_x, ans):
        #update var_x
        #update ans
        self.recursion(input, var_x, ans)

    def mySolution(self, input):
        ans = []
        var_x = 0
        self.recursion(input, var_x, ans)
        return ans
```

This solution fails to pass the test. But after I made a simple change, it passes:

```
class Solution(object):
    def recursion(self, input, ans):
        #update self.var_x
        #update ans
        self.recursion(input, ans)

    def mySolution(self, input):
        ans = []
        self.var_x = 0
        self.recursion(input, ans)
        return ans
```

What is the difference that declare var_x versus self.var_x? I think these two has the same effect in this problem, but one passes the test the other doesn't?

Comment: Please check your indentation.

Comment: surprising that it works better since you still do `prev = node` (no `self.prev`). Please provide a (properly indented) [mcve]

Comment: Since this is some sort of coding competition site, I don't want to say much, but you may have misunderstood the way they are presenting the data. It looks like you are getting an array representation of a packed binary tree, where the children of node N are numbered 2N and 2N+1. By contrast, you appear to be building an actual tree with node objects, and that may be ... overkill.

Comment: thanks for the reply. the input for the function is a treeNode object, Root. the website gives an array representation so that you can write your own test case.

Answer (score 0):

The semantic difference is simple: **var_x** is merely a local variable, one per call instance.  **self.var_x** is an attribute of the object, one per class instance.

If you need the value only within the one call instance, use **var_x** and don't bother the objects with storing the transient value.  If you need it as a long-term object property (attribute), then use **self.var_x**.